# IllegalArgument when clicking my map fragment twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

When I click on the button for the fragment containing the map, the map shows. When I click it again or click another fragment button and then click again on the button for the fragment containing the map, my app force quits and I get this explanation in LogCat:

*FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: BINARY XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment*
...
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line: #8: Duplicate id 0x7f070053, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment*

What to do? I'm guessing that it might have something to do with the fragment transaction manager but I really don't know?

**Fragment01.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment01.java**

```
public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void super.onDestroyView()
{
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
   FragmentTransaction ft =     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    StartFragment startfragment = new StartFragment();

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, startfragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void onSelectFragment(View view){

    Fragment newFragment;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnomforetaget)) {
        newFragment = new StartFragment();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnhittahit)) {
        newFragment = new Fragment01();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnhemsida)) {
        newFragment = new Fragment02();
    } else {
        newFragment = new StartFragment();
    }


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using the same map again and again (`Duplicate id 0x7f070053`) without destroying it first after you changed a fragment.

**solution:**

```
       public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
   super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
   FragmentTransaction ft =     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
}

}
```

it will destroy the map when you are replacing a fragment

Comment: I modified your code so it looks like this
`Fragment fragment = (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment);
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
  transaction.remove(fragment);
  transaction.commit();`

But now I instead get a java.langNullPointerException at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.java(651) and some other places as well?

Comment: @Sebbenator sorry but did you put it in the onDestroy method of the fragment?

Comment: No, I put it in the MainActivity. Shall I put it in the MainActivity in an onDestroy method? Or shall I put it in Fragment01?

Comment: @Sebbenator To the fragment where you added the map.. which is Fragment01.\

Comment: I copied your code (including the oncreate method) and put it in Fragment01 and it compiles. But I still get the original error (duplicate)?

Comment: @Sebbenator onDestroy not in onCreate

Comment: Yes,

`public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false); return v;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
}
}`

Right?

Comment: @Sebbenator try instead of onDestroy change it to onDestroyView if it didnt work post all the exception from the log cat

Comment: Now I get *FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment Fragment01{41c01b8 #1 id=0x7f070052} did not call through to super.onDestroyView()*.
I tried changing the code to `super.onDestroyView()` (wild guess) but that didn't work.

Comment: @Sebbenator put super.onDestroyView() before the code.. EDITTED

Comment: I get some markers on `super.onDestroyView()`:  *Return type for the method is missing* and *Syntax error on toxens, delete these tokens*. Plus *Duplicate method onDestroyView() in type Fragment01*. Shall I use only `super.onDestroyView()` or all three of them?

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I have edited my question, posting the current content of Fragment01.

Comment: Have you tried compiling that? I get markers on `super.onDestroyView()`: *Return type for the method is missing* and *Syntax error on toxens, delete these tokens*.

Comment: @Sebbenator thats is because you put super.onDestroyView as a name.. lawl.. editted again

Comment: Now It compiles but I'm getting the original fatal exception again: *FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment*...*at*...*(Fragment01.java:24)*...*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f070053, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment*

Comment: It actually works fine when clicling between fragments but crashes when clicking on Fragment01 when viewing Fragment01 (the map). Exception as above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It is working for me

```
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null)
        parent.removeView(view);
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
}
return view;
}
```